# decoding an asn.1 der octet string with bouncy castle

Tags: java, bouncycastle

I want to generate private key from DER encoded octet string.

```
0x3A:6B:2E:AA:0D:9F:25:A9:E4:55:98:3F:EB:5B:B9:47:52:81:21:91:1B:F3:B7:6B:E5:66:1C:89:DB:F2:4B:26
```

I have tried to convert to Byte ...

```
byte[] bytes = DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary(
    "3A6B2EAA0D9F25A9E455983FEB5BB947528121911BF3B76BE5661C89DBF24B26");
PKCS8EncodedKeySpec privSpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(bytes);
PrivateKey pkey = fact.generatePrivate(privSpec);
```

But didnt work. It throws Exception

```
"DEF length 107 object truncated by 77"
```

Can you please help?

Answer (score 1):

Your data does not look like valid [DER](http://luca.ntop.org/Teaching/Appunti/asn1.html) encoded data.

I tried to decode it with Peter Gutman's [dumpasn1](https://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/~pgut001/) and got:

```
dumpasn1 -ahlt xxx.der
```

> <3A 6B>
>      0 107: VisibleString {
>
> Error: Invalid data encountered at position 4: 2E AA.

A `DER OCTET-STRING` should have byte `0x06` as first tag byte.